# Error in excel file

Tags: xml, excel, logging

I have generated excel file.
When I try open it, I get error
"Problems came up in the following areas during load: Table".
I open log and found

```
XML ERROR in Table
REASON: Bad Value
FILE:   C:\test.xml
GROUP:  Cell
TAG:    Data
VALUE:   5

XML ERROR in Table
REASON: Bad Value
FILE:   C:\test.xml
GROUP:  Cell
TAG:    Data
VALUE:   5

XML ERROR in Table
REASON: Bad Value
FILE:   C:\test.xml
GROUP:  Cell
TAG:    Data
VALUE:   5

XML ERROR in Table
REASON: Bad Value
FILE:   C:\test.xml
GROUP:  Cell
TAG:    Data
VALUE:   5
```

How I can found where is error? It's big file about 80 Mb. Possible exist any tools which show info about error more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with openinng xml file in text editor and finding the places where `<Cell><Data>...</Data></Cell>` has value "5" or similar (with regex `<Cell.*>[\r\n\s]*<Data.*>5.*</Data>[\r\n\s]*</Cell>` for example).
After you identify the rows causing error you can compare them to the ones that don't. I think that the problem is Cell's style doesn't correspond to the value.

You can also try to repair the file with Excel (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/repairing-corrupted-files-in-excel-HA001034656.aspx)

If you identify problem rows but still can't figure out what the problem is, then upload truncated file somewhere